# Creating a Google search form that only returns C# results

Tags: html, search, form-submit

I know that I can create a google search box on my personal homepage using something like this (very basic code)

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
       <input type="text"  name="q"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</form>
```

Is it possible to change this to only return results containing C#.

If I enter stringbuilder, the above code submits 
      http://www.google.com/search?q=stringbuilder

whereas I want is 
http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+stringbuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google supports multiple `q` arguments. You can generate URLs like this: http://www.google.com/search?q=text1&q=text2. In your case, add a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="C#" />
```